# How can I control the quality of a screenshot in c#

Tags: c#, screenshot

I made a small windows form app that takes screenshots, but the final image looks a bit blurry compared to screenshots using other screenshot softwares. 
I mean like the pixel density on screenshots from my app is lower than the density of screenshots from other apps.
I used this tutorial: http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4630/capture-a-screen-shot/

How can I control the pixel density or quality of the screenshots my app takes, without resizing the images?

Comment: Modern screens offer 24 or 32 bits by pixel. Saving your image in GIF (8 bits per pixel => with a 256 colors palette) will certainly reduce the quality of your image.

Comment: I saved it as jpeg. I will try png though, because I noticed that most of the screenshots taken from any app is saved as PNG.

Comment: @LaurentLequenne ok you saved me, I don't know how I haven't thought about that. the PNG quality is really good, right what I wanted. I didn't use the GIF anyway.

Comment: Yes PNG is the best way... You could save also your JPEG with a higher quality (100%) but it still loses some info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was just the image format. Probably jpeg format has lower quality than png when taking screenshot. Saving the image as png gave me a real sharp and high quality screenshot.